# Installing dependencies with Python Poetry is stuck on "Pending..."

Tags: python, pip, raspbian, python-poetry

I am using Raspbian 11
I ran these to commands, and it says "Pending".

```
pip3 install poetry 
poetry install
```

I deleted the virtual environment and retried but same error.

```
- Updating certifi (2023.7.22 -> 2022.12.7): Pending...
- Updating charset-normalizer (3.2.0 -> 2.1.1): Pending...
- Installing markupsafe (2.1.2): Pending...
- Installing pytz (2023.3): Pending...
- Updating urllib3 (1.26.16 -> 1.26.14): Pending...
- Updating zipp (3.16.2 -> 3.11.0): Pending...
```

Comment: You might have network issues.

Comment: I added dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8  
rebbooted, and I can ping google.com 

I think this is  DLL-hell scenario. In VENV, I reran pip3 install poetry and got : Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 0):

I also had very different and erratic results when downloading. Quite troublesome and not really plausible why it sometimes works and sometimes not. For me the following method did the trick. Downloads are slower, but after the change at least not pending anymore (Ubuntu 22.04).

```
poetry config installer.modern-installation false
```

For more details see here:
https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#installermodern-installation

For older versions of Poetry there was another flag:
https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.4.0/

I've also read reducing the max workers to 1 could work. But since the other method worked, I didn't investigate this any further.

```
poetry config installer.max-workers 1
```

Strangely it was always pending with the urllib package. So I assume that the combination of packages might also influence this.